# Beginner Microsoft power point one picture at a time

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Hi I am doing a presentation and wanted to know how I could display one picture at a time on each slide because right now if I click a slide it displays all the pictures at once. I want to display each picture by itself so I can talk about it .

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the picture and add an animation (Animation Ribbon).
2. Make sure the Animation Pane is displaying.
3. Select the next picture and add an animation.
4. Now use the drop-down for the second picture on the animation pane and set the animation to "Start on Click".

Repeat steps 3 and 4 for each picture or element you want to show. If you set the animation to "Appear with previous" you can make more than one element appear with one click.

Answer (score 1):

Simply select each picture and apply an animation.

Then switch to presentation mode and each click will introduce the next picture until they have all been shown.

However, that might be tricky to do on a single page with lots of pictures. The alternative is to put each picture on a separate page, all with the same layout and animate the page transitions instead.